# Parsing single word into multiple tokens while skipping whitespace

Tags: antlr4

I have a language where whitespace is insignificant so I skip it. Here is a subset of the grammar I have so far:

```
start: expr <EOF>;
expr
    : atom
    | expr '|' expr
    | expr expr+
    | '{' expr '}'
    ;
atom
    : ATOM_TOKEN
    ;
fragment LETTER: [a-zA-Z];
fragment DIGIT: [0-9];
ATOM_TOKEN: (LETTER | DIGIT)+;
WS: [ \r\n\t]+ -> skip;
```

When executed on the following input (note the whitespace and lack thereof) it correctly produces the desired expected parse tree:

```
{hello42   |  hi world}|{good bye} red blue green
```

[image: Parse Tree]

Now, my problem is that I would ideally like to make `atom` a nested rule so that I can pick out the representative pieces.

Here is an example grammar:

```
atom: atomToken+;
atomToken
    : LETTERS
    | DIGITS
    ;
LETTERS: LETTER+;
DIGITS: DIGIT+;
```

and the result of running `he11o` through it (note 1's instead of L's):

[image: Atom Parse Tree]

The problem with this approach is that since spaces are ignored something like `he11o world` will now parse as a single `atom`.

Is there anything obvious I'm missing? From my research a couple of possibilities come up.

1. Write a secondary grammar to use when I actually need to extract the pieces of an `atom`. This one seems like the easiest solution.
2. Implement some sort of token injection by subclassing the generated Lexer. This seems very hacky and I would like to avoid it unless there is no better option.
3. Do something with lexical modes or channels so that the whitespace is skipped only conditionally? I'm pretty sure this won't work since the context to trigger this would come from the parser and as far as I know you can't change lexer behavior from parser rules.
4. Don't skip the whitespace and instead litter the main grammar with all possible whitespace occurrences.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by representative pieces of an atom?

Comment: In this example each "atom" is comprised of either letters of digits. I would ideally like to be able to decompose the atom rule to the atomToken rule that captures runs of letters or digits. So he11o would turn into (he) (11) (o)